# Do all macro lenses have dark shadows when shooting?

Tags: lens

Is it normal for a macro lens purchased to have dark shadows during photography? If so, how can I use this shadow to perfect my photography?

Comment: What sort of shadows are you thinking about?  Macro lenses when used as intended are rather close to the subject so the lens and camera can cast shadows.  Lighting a macro subject is a challenge.

Comment: Are you talking about shadows cast by the camera and lens blocking some of the light that would otherwise be falling on the subject? Or are you talking about the image being darker on the edges and particularly in the corners when using wider angle macro lenses?

Answer (score 2):

Many macro photographers use a ring light, such as [this US$40 unit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08NMTDYCL), to eliminate shadows cast by the camera body, lens, and photographer. Some ring lights come with a selection of color filters to match ambient lighting. Some can be used as a [flash (strobe)](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/ring-camera-light-macro-flash/ci/649/N/4168864821).

Ring lighting may be **too** diffuse and even, in some applications, but just wrap some foil over a segment of the ring to make it more directional.